# how to fetch the data from parent table data based on child table data in many to many relationship in bidirectional using hibernate and spring

Tags: spring-mvc

i have two tables like below in many to many relationship in oracle database.

Student table
..................
ID(primary key)
FIRSTNAME
LASTNAME
EMAIL
PHONE

### Course table

Column Name 
............
ID(primary key)
ROOM
NAME

these are the two tables i have and the intermediate table is like this

Student_Course
..............
Column Name 
..........
STUDENT_ID(primary key and foregin key from student table)
COURSE_ID(primary key and foregin key from course table)

i have two entity classes for this

Student.java
.........

```
import javax.persistence.*;




import java.util.*;




@Entity


@Table(name = "student")


public class Student {


@Id


@GeneratedValue


private Integer id;




// @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,cascade =
// CascadeType.ALL,targetEntity=Course.class)
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "student_course", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "student_id"),          inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "course_id"))
private List<Course> follows;

@Column
private String firstname;

@Column
private String lastname;

@Column
private String email;

@Column
private String phone;

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public List<Course> getFollows() {
    return follows;
}

public void setFollows(List<Course> follows) {
    this.follows = follows;
}

public String getFirstname() {
    return firstname;
}

public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
}

public String getLastname() {
    return lastname;
}

public void setLastname(String lastname) {
    this.lastname = lastname;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
}

public void setPhone(String phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
}
```

}

Course.java
............

```
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import java.util.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "course")
public class Course {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Integer id;

// @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,cascade =
// CascadeType.ALL,targetEntity=Student.class)
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "student_course", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "course_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "student_id"))
private List<Student> followedBy;

private String room;

private String name;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public List<Student> getFollowedBy() {
    return followedBy;
}

public void setFollowedBy(List<Student> followedBy) {
    this.followedBy = followedBy;
}

public String getRoom() {
    return room;
}

public void setRoom(String room) {
    this.room = room;
}
```

}

here the relationship works correctly...

students.jsp
....................................
in this page this displays the student data along with two links one for adding the courses  to the student and one for deleting the student
..........................................

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>

<h2>Users Manager</h2>

<form:form method="post" action="addstudent.html" commandName="student">

<table>
<tr>
    <td><form:label path="firstname"><spring:message code="label.firstname"/>         </form:label></td>
    <td><form:input path="firstname" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><form:label path="lastname"><spring:message code="label.lastname"/></form:label></td>
    <td><form:input path="lastname" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><form:label path="email"><spring:message code="label.email"/></form:label></td>
    <td><form:input path="email" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><form:label path="phone"><spring:message code="label.telephone"/></form:label></td>
    <td><form:input path="phone" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        <input type="submit" value="<spring:message code="label.add"/>"/>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form:form>
<h3>Users</h3>
<c:if  test="${!empty studentsList}">
<table>
<tr>
<th><spring:message code="label.lastname"/></th>
<th><spring:message code="label.firstname"/></th>
<th><spring:message code="label.email"/></th>
<th><spring:message code="label.telephone"/></th>
<th>&nbsp;</th>
<th>&nbsp;</th>
</tr>
<c:forEach items="${studentsList}" var="student">
<tr>
    <td>${student.lastname}</td>
    <td>${student.firstname}</td>
    <td>${student.email}</td>
    <td>${student.phone}</td>
    <td><a href="delete/${student.id}"><spring:message code="label.remove"/></a></td>
    <td><a href="studentcourses/${student.id}"><spring:message code="label.courses"/>         
</a></td>    </tr>
</c:forEach>
</table>
</c:if>
```

............................
on clicking the courses link courses page with one dropdown list containing list of courses from the courses table will be displayed here we are selecting the course and assign it to the student.

courses.jsp
.............

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>

<h2>Courses Manager</h2>

<form:form method="post" action="addcourse.html" commandName="course">

<table>
<tr>
    <td><form:label path="room"><spring:message code="label.room"/></form:label></td>
    <td><form:input path="room"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><form:label path="name"><spring:message code="label.name"/></form:label></td>
    <td><form:input path="name"/></td>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        <input type="submit" value="<spring:message code="label.add"/>"/>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form:form>

<h3>Courses</h3>
<c:if  test="${!empty coursesList}">
<table class="data">
<tr>
<th><spring:message code="label.name"/></th>
<th><spring:message code="label.room"/></th>
<th></th>
</tr>
<c:forEach items="${coursesList}" var="course">
<tr>
    <td>${course.name }</td>
    <td>${course.room}</td>
    <td><a href="courses/delete/${course.id}">delete</a></td>
</tr>

</c:forEach>
</table>
</c:if>
<c:if test="${!empty students}">
<table class="data">
<tr>
<th><spring:message code="label.firstname"></spring:message></th>
<th><spring:message code="label.lastname"></spring:message></th>
<th><spring:message code="label.email"></spring:message></th>
<th><spring:message code="label.telephone"></spring:message></th>
</tr>
<c:forEach items="${students}" var="student">
<tr>
<td>
${student.firstname}
</td>
<td>
${student.lastname}
</td>
<td>
${student.email}
</td>
<td>
${student.phone}
</td>

</tr>
</c:forEach>
</table>
</c:if>
```

in this jsp list of courses will be displayed...
my question how can we display the list of students in the particular course..
i tried to get the students based on the course using the following code..............

```
From Course c
```

here i get the correct details of students under particular course but i failed to display them as

```
course name.....>student1
           .....>student2
           ......>student3
```

like that i want to display the details...can any one please suggest me to achieve this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

${course.followedBy} should return the list of student under a current course. Then you can itterate it

```
...
<c:forEach items="${coursesList}" var="course">
...
<c:forEach items="${course.followedBy}" var="student">
</c:forEach>

</c:forEach>
...
```